# Magento 2 Override default header template

Tags: magento2, overrides, phtml, header

I have created my own theme by extending the `Magento/Blank` theme.

Now want to override the default header template files **`link.phtml`, `topmenu.phtml`, `header.phtml`** which is located at `vendor/module-theme/view/frontend/templates` into my theme.

My theme is located at `app/design/frontend/MyModule/MyTheme`

So please let me know how I can override and what will be the structure for it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

copy `templates` folder from

`vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates`

and `paste` into

`app/design/frontend/MySpaceName/MyTheme/Magento_Theme/`paste templates folder  here

Comment: Works for my Magento 2.1.0