# Magento 2 - source code

Tags: installation, putty

I have installed Magento 2 on Ubuntu server because I tried to run it on my localhost but it was extremely slow. So I installed it via Putty and now everything  is working fast. My question is, where do u find the source code if u want to make some custom changes inside of the code??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2 Override default header template](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105538/magento-2-override-default-header-template)

Answer (score 1):

Without more details here is a link that will help you find a lot of file locations:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html
There is a section for theme, layouts, and templates.
Because Magento is open source you can also look at the github for more information. 
https://github.com/magento/magento2

Please let me know if you have more a server question and are trying to find the files on your server.

Comment: Regarding the more details.. I installed it on the Digital Ocean server, and after I ran the composer the www/html/ folder is completely empty. The IP adress is running and I can open the admin panel, but the var folder is completely empty which means I cant get to the source code...

Comment: I think that it is okay, since the var folder just has the htcaccess in the github source, and looking at mine it looks like just backups and caches, which you can just create.  Most of the actual code is probably going to be in something like app or skin or a custom theme folder.

Comment: I'd maybe post a screenshot of your file structure so you can see what you are missing